# Different layout rendering between Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a website built in WordPress, the footer section is rendered as desired on Safari: [image: Footer on Safari]

However on google chrome it looks as follows: [image: Footer on Google Chrome]

Why it renders differently? and how it can be fixed to be displayed properly across all browsers?

Thanks you.

Comment: Can you post the CSS code relating to the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not working because you used an invalid value for "Float" in ".footer-widget".
Instead of using "center", try using "left".